# When to prefer const lvalue reference over rvalue reference templates

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Currently reading the codebase for cpr requests library:
https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr/blob/master/include/cpr/api.h

Noticed that the interface for this library uses perfect forwarding quite often. Just learning rvalue references so this is all relatively new to me.

From my understanding, the benefit with rvalue references, templating, and forwarding is that the function call being wrapped around will take its arguments by rvalue reference rather than by value. Which avoids unnecessary copying. It also prevents one from having to generate a bunch of overloads due to reference deduction.

However, from my understanding, const lvalue reference essentially does the same thing. It prevents the need for overloads and passes everything by reference. With the caveat that if the function being wrapped around takes a non-const reference, it won't compile.

However if everything within the call stack won't need a non-const reference, then why not just pass everything by const lvalue reference?

I guess my main question here is, when should you use one over the other for best performance? Attempted to test this with the below code. Got the following relatively consistent results:

Compiler: gcc 6.3
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9

```
<<<<
Passing rvalue!
const l value: 2912214
rvalue forwarding: 2082953
Passing lvalue!
const l value: 1219173
rvalue forwarding: 1585913
>>>>
```

These results stay fairly consistent between runs. It appears that for an rvalue arg, the const l value signature is slightly slower, though I'm not exactly sure why, unless I'm misunderstanding this and const lvalue reference does in fact make a copy of the rvalue.

For lvalue arg, we see the counter, rvalue forwarding is slower. Why would this be? Shouldn't the reference deduction always produce a reference to an lvalue? If thats the case shouldn't it be more or less equivalent to the const lvalue reference in terms of performance?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <time.h>

std::string func1(const std::string& arg) {
    std::string test(arg);
    return test;
}

template <typename T>
std::string func2(T&& arg) {
    std::string test(std::forward<T>(arg));
    return test;
}

void wrap1(const std::string& arg) {
    func1(arg);
}

template <typename T>
void wrap2(T&& arg) {
    func2(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

int main()
{
     auto n = 100000000;

     /// Passing rvalue
     std::cout << "Passing rvalue!" << std::endl;

     // Test const l value
     auto t = clock();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         wrap1("test");
     std::cout << "const l value: " << clock() - t << std::endl;

     // Test rvalue forwarding
     t = clock();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         wrap2("test");
     std::cout << "rvalue forwarding: " <<  clock() - t << std::endl;

     std::cout << "Passing lvalue!" << std::endl;

     /// Passing lvalue
     std::string arg = "test";

     // Test const l value
     t = clock();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         wrap1(arg);
     std::cout << "const l value: " << clock() - t << std::endl;

     // Test rvalue forwarding
     t = clock();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         wrap2(arg);
     std::cout << "rvalue forwarding: " << clock() - t << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, a forwarding reference (`T&&` - with The being a template type parameter in a deduction context (aka function parameters) is something different than an r-value reference (like `std::string&&`). The former will bind to anything, the latter only to temporaries.

Comment: Oh, and when you post benchmark results, please also add the compiler, it's version and compilation flags.

Comment: `std::forward<T&>(arg)` should be `std::forward<T>(arg)`. Sorry for spamming the comments.

Comment: The important difference is whether your hypothetical function call argument is ever looked at again by anything other than the function body. If not, forwarding allows you to *move* the value along to any potential consumer inside the function when a private copy is required, whereas your proposed alternative would always result in an "full" copy. If the function doesn't consume anything, then there's no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [here are](https://ideone.com/X1yzPe) slightly different results from your code. As mentioned in comments, compiler and its settings are very important. In particular, you may notice that all cases have similar runtime, except for the first one, which is about twice as slow.

```
Passing rvalue!
const l value: 1357465
rvalue forwarding: 669589
Passing lvalue!
const l value: 744105
rvalue forwarding: 713189
```

Let's look at exactly what happens in each case.

1) When calling `wrap1("test")`, since signature of that function expects a `const std::string &`, the char array you are passing will be implicitly converted to a temporary `std::string` object on every call (i.e. `n` times), which involves a copy* of the value. A const reference to that temporary will then be passed into `func1`, where another `std::string` is constructed from it, which again involves a copy (since it's a const reference, it cannot be moved from, despite being in fact a temporary). Even though the function returns by value, due to RVO that copy would be guaranteed to be elided if the return value was used. In this case the return value is not used, and I'm not entirely sure whether the standard allows the compiler to optimize away the construction of `temp`. I suspect not, since in general such construction could have observable side effects (and your results suggest it does not get optimized away). To sum up, a full-on construction and destruction of `std::string` is performed twice in this case.

2) When calling `wrap2("test")`, the argument type is `const char[5]`, and it gets forwarded as an rvalue reference all the way to `func2`, where an `std::string` constructor from a `const char[]` is called that copies the value. The deduced type of template parameter `T` is `const char[5] &&` and, quite obviously, it cannot be moved from despite being an rvalue reference (due to both being `const` and *not* being an `std::string`). Compared to the previous case, construction/destruction of a string only happens once per call (the `const char[5]` literal is always in memory and incurs no overhead).

3) When calling `wrap1(arg)`, you are passing an lvalue as a `const string &` through the chain, and one copy constructor is called in `func1`.

4) When calling `wrap2(arg)`, this is similar to the previous case, since the deduced type for `T` is `const std::string &`.

5) I'm assuming your test was designed to demonstrate the advantage of perfect forwarding when a copy of the argument needs to be made at the bottom of the call chain (hence the creation of `temp`). In this case, you need to replace the `"test"` argument in first two cases with `std::string("test")` in order to truly have an `std::string &&` argument, and also fix your perfect forwarding to be `std::forward<T>(arg)`, as mentioned in comments. In that case, [the results](https://ideone.com/YvnljA) are:

```
Passing rvalue!
const l value: 1314630
rvalue forwarding: 595084
Passing lvalue!
const l value: 712461
rvalue forwarding: 720338
```

which is similar to what we had before, but now actually invoking a move constructor.

I hope this helps explain the results. There may be some other issues related to inlining of function calls and other compiler optimizations, which would help explain the smaller discrepancies between cases 2-4.

As to your question which approach to use, I suggest reading Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++" items 23-30. Apologies for a book reference instead of a direct answer, but there is no silver bullet, and the optimal choice is always case-dependent, so it's better to just understand the trade-offs of each design decision.

---

* A copy constructor may or may not involve dynamic memory allocation due to Short String Optimization; thanks to ytoledano for bringing this up in the comments. Also, I've implicitly assumed throughout the answer that a copy is significantly more expensive that a move, which is not always the case.

Comment: Regarding calling `wrap("test")` - a temporary is created by there isn't necessarily a dynamic allocation - the string implementation might be using Short String Optimization which keeps short strings on the stack.

Comment: @ytoledano thanks for the comment! I've adjusted the answer to mention this. gcc definitely seems to use SSO in this case

Comment: @SergeyKlevtsov thanks for the answer Sergey, this does a great job of explaining the usage. Huge help.